# Grep number extraction

Tags: linux, terminal, grep

I need to extract the numerical value, using grep, from a series of lines with this format: "The total difference is: 11.7423485766".

Here the format of the file

```
smoothSolver:  Solving for Uax, Initial residual = 0.00117823324374, Final residual = 2.6551659504e-06, No Iterations 4

smoothSolver:  Solving for Uay, Initial residual = 0.00102460810826, Final residual = 2.27551114222e-06, No Iterations 4

GAMG:  Solving for pa, Initial residual = 0.083060886073, Final residual = 4.42348716834e-05, No Iterations 8

Adjoint continuity errors : sum local = 0.000102057393701, global = -2.79342190934e-05, cumulative = -0.00156476995631

The ratio scalar is 0.00767871345324

The toal volume  is 0.01

The percentage of fluid domain  is 0.767871345324

omegaVol is 1.331

Total Pressure at the inlet: 18.3146365858

Total Pressure at the outlet: 0.533553352625

The total difference is: 17.7810832332

ExecutionTime = 1.05 s
```

I tried

```
grep "The total difference is:" | cut -d' ' -f9   log
```

but it seems not to work and I don't understand why.

Any idea? Thanks for help

Comment: If I understood correctly, you should use
grep "The total difference is:" | cut -d' ' -f5 log

Comment: Hello @M.Falzone thank you for the quick reply. Maybe I should have added how my file is composed. I've just updated the main thread.

Comment: Your example sentence contains 5 blank separated fields, but you're trying to get the 9th field. Is this a full line of input?

Comment: @BenjaminW. I've just update the format file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this:

```
grep "The total difference is:" log | grep -o "[0-9.]*"
```

The first `grep` takes the entire line, containing the matching text, the second one takes only the digits.

Comment: Thank you man, it works. Anyway I would like to understand also this syntax I found somewhere:  >>>grep 'Solving for Uy' | cut -d' ' -f9 | tr -d ','<<<

Answer (score 3):

Dominique's answer is correct. Just for completeness, your error is, that you specify no file for grep. So you enter interactive mode of grep.

When you do it like this it works:

```
grep "The total difference is:" log | cut -d' ' -f5
```

P.S.: you were also selecting the wrong field. It's 5, not 9.