# grep command trying to fetch numeric value

Tags: linux, unix, grep, numeric

From below text in file:

```
current_build: 22
previous_build: 55
```

I am only trying to grep number value of current_build.

When run following command

```
grep -o -E '[0-9]+' textfile
```

The output is both number like below

```
22    
55
```

How do i only grep the value `22`

Comment: `awk '/current_build/{print $2}' file`

Comment: Overlooked your comment. This should be your answer! :) (At least I would mention it in the main answer)

Comment: Check my answer in "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53211019/grep-number-extraction/", you just need to replace the words "The total difference is:" by "current_build:".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grep number extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53211019/grep-number-extraction)

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -Po 'current_build: \K.*' file
```

> `\K`: removes matching part before \K

Output:

```
22
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `awk` because it is portable in opposite to grep `-o` which only works with GNU grep:

```
awk '/current_build/{print $NF}' file
```

`awk` splits the input into *fields*. The default field separator is a sequence of *blank* chars. `NF` is the *number of fields*, `$NF` is the last field.

Answer (score 0):

Only print lines matching `current_build` at the start of the line and show the part after the last space:

```
sed -n 's/current_build:.* //p' file
```